# 14.04 - Unable to lock/move items to/from unity launcher

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, icons

When I right-click on an application's icon on the launcher, and select "Lock to launcher", the contextual menu never disappears. Despite that, pressing escape to get out of the menu and then closing the application does not remove the icon, suggesting to me that it "worked".

But on the other hand, when I do the same for "Unlock from launcher", the icon still remains. I don't have a way to *remove* the icon after it's been locked to the launcher.

Additionally, when I click-and-hold an icon for 2 seconds to move the icon, the icon appears to follow/be anchored to the cursor to allow me to move it. However, subsequently clicking the mouse anywhere does not release the icon to be moved; instead I have to right-click or press escape to cancel.

I'm sure you can imagine my frustration at this. Please help.

I have tried:

- [Is it possible to permanently lock launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162877/is-it-possible-to-permanently-lock-launcher-icons)
- [I can not move icons in Unity Launcher.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310428/i-can-not-move-icons-in-unity-launcher)
- [How do I clean up my dconf database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45535/how-do-i-clean-up-my-dconf-database)

...but of course I still am unable to lock or move icons or I wouldn't be here. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or how to figure out what's broken?

Are there error or message logs I can look at? Are there specific executables or permissions I can look at? What configuration files are related to the applications here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the associated `.desktop` file and remove it.

Look for the `.desktop` file in these folders:

```
/usr/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications/
```

When you find it, remove the file with `sudo rm -f file.desktop`. Next time you reboot it should be gone. If you can't find it, you can always search the entire hard drive with:

```
sudo find / -name "*.desktop"
```

Comment: While that seems like a reasonable _workaround_, I would rather fix the underlying problem: that the launcher is not behaving as expected.

Comment: I would check who owns the .desktop file. If it's own by root, your normal user won't be able to delete or modify the file. You can change the owner with `chown`.

Comment: I don't believe my user is _supposed_ to own `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` though? There's also several `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` which aren't in the launcher which tells me that they should be able to be added/removed/locked/etc without removing the file

Comment: You are right. I was referring to the files in `~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: I edited my comment, I suspect after you'd replied. I'd added _"There's also several .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications which aren't in the launcher which tells me that they should be able to be added/removed/locked/etc without removing the file"_

Comment: It looks like my answer didn't help much. At this point I can't think of any solution to your problem, other than the generic reset unity but I don't know if that would solve it either... good luck. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is the with `unity`. So these steps should help, open terminal then run following command:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 sudo apt-get install unity
```

if the above don't work try resetting `unity` using the following commands in the `terminal`

```
 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
 setsid unity
```

And this should give you back the default icons if you need them

```
 unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: I successfully executed the commands and then rebooted. However, the problem still persists. :(

Comment: I have updated the answer, try those and let me know.

Comment: I do not need the default icons. Indeed, I want to _remove_ them. I issued `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`, followed by `setsid unity`; the GUI reset itself and I had to log back in. The icons are still there and I'm still unable to unlock from launcher.